# how to reload listview from another activity (adapter) class

Tags: android, arrays, listview, adapter

i have tried all the things but i cant get proper result,i also try

```
adapter.clearAll()
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

but i cant get result when i delete row from list view its deleted from its position but when i change value of another row than the delete process working perfectly but changed value not set.getting value from database perfectly.

Here is my code please help me and tell where i m doing wrong.

**Thank you in advance**

```
Delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String Identifier_fev = null;
        String Default_Option = null;
        String Quantity1 = null;
        jffDatabase.open();
        Cursor identifie = jffDatabase.getALL();
        if (identifie.moveToPosition(position)) {
            Identifier_fev = identifie.getString(identifie.getColumnIndexOrThrow("identifier"));
           Default_Option = identifie.getString(identifie.getColumnIndexOrThrow("default_option"));
        }

         jffDatabase.delete(Identifier_fev, Default_Option);
        identifier.remove(position);
        title.remove(position);
       defaultPrice.remove(position);
        default_option.remove(position);
        price.remove(position);
        quantity.remove(position);


            Cursor c1 = jffDatabase.getALL();
            if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Quantity1 = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("quantity"));
                    update_quantity.add(Quantity1);

                } while (c1.moveToNext());
            }
                for (int i = 0; i < update_quantity.size(); i++) {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "" + update_quantity, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                  Quantitylbl.setText(update_quantity.get(i).toString());


                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "set " + Quantitylbl.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


        Quantity();
      notifyDataSetChanged()
      AddtoCartActivity.Cartcount.setText(String.valueOf(sum));

    }

});
```

Comment: Where is your adapter? How is the data from the database gets into the adapter?

Comment: i have used BaseAdapter

Comment: Show the code of where you tried to call `notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: @AleksG thanx for interest and sorry i forgot this i call this method after Quantity(); that i changed

Comment: That is still not clear.  `notifyDataSetChanged` needs to be called on an adapter.  How are you doing it?  Where is your reference to the adapter on which you are calling it?

Comment: when i try 'adapter. notifyDataSetChanged' its not working than i tried just calling 'notifyDataSetChanged'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126524/discussion-between-aleks-g-and-seggy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good practice is use Interface

Create new Interface

```
public interface MyCustomObjectListener {
      public void RefreshList();   
     //add parameter for delete if required  ex-   
     //public void RefreshList(String Item_id);     
  }
```

then implement Activity by this Interface

```
YourActivityName extends Activity implements MyCustomObjectListener
```

And Implement Method

```
   @Override
   public void RefreshList() {
        // Do your delete task and clear current List and get updated list task here
   }
```

and from Base adapter onClick you can call method RefreshList like this

```
((YourActivityName)mContext).RefreshList();
```

you can delete and refresh list from  `@Override` `RefreshList`